# Receive information from game server and immediate update to website

Tags: html

Reference to title.

Is that possible to receive an information from game server and immediate update in our website?

Example of Game Server: http://maple.asiasoftsea.com/index

If possible, which method should I use?

Does it consider as illegal action?

Thank you very much.

P/S : Sorry if I put wrong the wrong tag. Because I don't know which tag should I use. And sorry for asking a bad question.

And thank for those people who correct me.

Comment: You should probably also specify whether this is your game server or someone else's. Can you explain further what you're trying to do?

Comment: Certainly not using HTML alone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've let a lot out of your post, but I'm going to go really in depth regardless.

---

> Is that possible to receive an information from game server and
>   immediate update in our website?

Yes it is possi...

> If possible which method should I use?

...ble. I'm getting there.

Your best bet is to use [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). This will allow you to update your website without your website being reloaded. This usually happens by clicking on a button, which will pull in the new information from wherever you're getting it from.

You have to think about what the "game server" is using to display their content, however, and how you can retrieve it. I'm guessing that this content is not hosted on your own domain, so you'll need to make a cross domain AJAX script. A good tutorial for this can be found [here](http://usejquery.com/posts/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide).

You mentioned that you want the page to automatically load the new content. The usual way an `AJAX` request is made is through user interaction, but I suppose you could have it check for new content on an interval, or have it check the current content with the remote content and see if there are changes, and if there are, pull in the new content.

> Does it consider as illegal action?

Is it illegal to do this? If it's your own site and your own content, then no. If it's someone else's, you should probably get their permission before using it.

Comment: Thanks.
I had learnt a lot from you. XD

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest thinking about something like Ajax if you don't want your webpage to reload on each request/response/update.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if you own the game server and if not if they provide an api for you to gather information from (Counter strike I believe has an api for this). If you have access then Comet is the keyword/buzzword you need to research. Per [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29):

> Comet is a web application model in which a long-held HTTP request
>   allows a web server to push data to a browser, without the browser
>   explicitly requesting it

Among techniques used are long polling, hidden iframes, and an older technique that makes use of java applets.

An example implementation is [ape](http://www.ape-project.org/) or ajax push engine. It is an open source project that implements ajax push. Includes a server and js framework.

An example of long polling can be found [here](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/rg28/index.html?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter) and there is a stack overflow posting for exmaples here: [Online tutorials for implementing comets (server push)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824604/online-tutorials-for-implementing-comets-server-push)